# Samsung Tizen Timer settings

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I was built a samsung smart TV app, and there is a timer on the device, what sets up the turn on and the turn off periods to the device.
Can I update that periods via web application?

Comment: Please be more specific. Give more details.

Comment: It is an web app, (JS,CSS, HTML), and I want to update the device timer:
For example 9-10 online 10-12 offline 12-19 online. or what specification do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. There is an API to do just that:

www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/APIReference/SSSP4/tizen2821/index.html#setOnTimer

It's hard to find that documentation. If you scroll up at the page I linked you will see a summary of methods, there is a whole section for timer-settings.

Example from the link:

```
var onSuccess = function(val) {
  console.log("[setOnTimer] success : " + val);
};
var onError = function(error) {
  console.log("[setOnTimer] code :" + error.code + " error name: " +                   error.name + "  message " +  error.message);
};
console.log("[setOnTimer] ");
b2bapis.b2bcontrol.setOnTimer("TIMER6","21:30", onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Thank you for yours answer, finally im also found it, and the other important thing, that your application needs to generate a b2b certificate in TizenStudio

Comment: You're welcome. The certificate is related to app deployment rather than the API afaik.

Comment: Addendum - it's related to both.